# Pasar parámetro con formato al controller de MVC 5 desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mvc

Tengo el siguiente JavaScript:

```
var FchActIng = f.getFullYear() + "/" + (f.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + f.getDate();
 $.ajax({ type: 'Post',
          dataType: 'Json',
          data: { IdMaq: CodMaq, Fecha_Uso: FchActIng, IdTurno: valturno },
          url: "/Turnos/BuscTurnos",})
```

el cual debe pasar la fecha en formato `yyyy/mm/dd`, al controller que tiene la siguiente definición:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BuscTurnos(Control_Turno Control_Turno)
        {
          using (ControlTurnos = new APPWEBEntities())
            {
              try
              {                    
                var BuscTurnos = ControlTurnos.SP_Sel_Maq_Fecha_Ant(Control_Turno.IdMaq,
                                 Convert.ToString(Control_Turno.Fecha_Uso),
                                 Convert.ToString(Control_Turno.IdTurno)).ToList();
                return Json(BuscTurnos);
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  object BuscTurnos = null;
                  return Json(BuscTurnos = 2);
              }
           }
        }
```

El problema es que no está pasando el parámetro al controller y no deduzco cuál es el problema.

saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar más información sobre "no está pasando el parámetro al controller"? ¿Cómo lo sabes? ¿Tienes trazas de error en un log (en ese caso, ayudará que las añadas)? ¿Qué es `f` (parece un date, pero lo es seguro)? ¿La petición se lanza y sale del browser correctamente? ¿Haciendo debug la información no es la que esperas (en ese caso, un pantallazo también puede ayudar)? Aportando la mayor información la comunidad podrá ayudarte más fácilmente :)

Comment: si ,  la idea es que se pase la fecha hacia    Convert.ToString(Control_Turno.Fecha_Uso), para después tomarla en un SP y en base a otros campos poder realizar una consulta, cuando verifico en el controller solo me toma la fecha dd/mm/yyyy, lo que no me sirve, pues la necesito en yy/mm/dd

Comment: Entonces, si te he entendido correctamente, la fecha te llega al controller, pero con formato `dd/mm/yyyy` y tú lo que necesitas es que te llegue la fecha como una cadena con formato `yyyy/mm/dd` (nota: en tu comentario pone "yy" y en la pregunta "yyyy", ¿cuál sería el formato correcto que necesitas)? ¿Podrías añadir también cómo le estás asignando valor a la variable `f` porfa?

Comment: es yyyy/mm/dd, es seria el formato, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en el valor que se está armando en `Fecha_Uso`, es decir, la variable `FchActIng`.

Asumiendo que `f` es una variable de tipo Date (se preguntaba en los comentarios pero no lo has confirmado), tu código hace tal que:

```js
// Obtener la fecha y hora actual (puede variar cuando se ejecute)
const f = new Date();

// Imprime la fecha. Fíjate que el mes en este caso (enero cuando
// se escribe la respuesta), lo marca como "1" en lugar de "01",
// por tanto, tu fecha sería 2021/1/19
console.log('f: ', f);
var FchActIng = f.getFullYear() + "/" + (f.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + f.getDate();
console.log('FchActIng: ', FchActIng);
```

Y el formato es incorrecto, ya que el mes lo está formando con un sólo dígito. Para forzar al formato que necesitas, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const now = new Date(2021, 0, 19, 10, 10, 0);  // Martes 19 de Enero de 2021
console.log('Fecha de test: ', now);

const formattedDate = now.getFullYear() + '/' + 
  ((+now.getMonth() < 10) ? `0${now.getMonth() + 1}` : now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
  ((+now.getDate() < 10) ? `0${now.getDate()}` : now.getDate());

// Fecha en formato yyyy/mm/dd, con m en el rango [1, 12]
console.log('Result: ', formattedDate);
```

Ahora en ese momento al servidor ya se envía el formato correcto.